# Qt project with Boost

Tags: qt, boost, c++14

I have a Qt project which requires boost.  The project works fine in Linux, but compiling on windows has presented some difficulties.  I have been able to make it work, but not properly, and that bothers me.

Here's the relevant part of .pro (working)

```
win32{
    INCLUDEPATH +=C:\Boost\Boost
    LIBS += "C:\Boost\Boost\stage\lib\libboost_system-mgw53-mt-1_65_1.a"
    LIBS += -lws2_32
}
```

This does not work, but should according to the documentation I've found online.

```
win32{
    INCLUDEPATH +=C:\Boost\Boost
    LIBS += -LC:\Boost\Boost\stage\lib -lboost_system-mt
    LIBS += -lws2_32
}
```

Note: Boost was compiled using the mingw distributed with Qt Creator.

Comment: Not sure, but for the sake of clarity what's the error you're encountering?

Comment: :-1: error: cannot find -lboost_system-mt and

collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status

(Copy-pasted from the Issues section of Qt Creator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found the solution!  I noticed that I had two copies of every boost library in \stage\lib.

`libboost_system-mgw53-mt-1_65_1.a` and `libboost_system-mgw53-mt-d-1_65_1.a`

I compiled the project using both and while the former had some warnings, the latter did not.  Removing `libboost_system-mgw53-mt-1_65_1.a` from the folder allowed `-lboost_system-mt` to work just fine.

I don't know why I had both of these files, but it was undoubtedly due to me fumbling around with compiling boost.

Comment: `-d` stands for *debug* version as opposed to *release*. See [Library Naming](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming).

Comment: Hmm...  It appears outputting both debug and release is the default for boost.  I wonder why that confuses mingw.